# Uninstall Packages that aren't used by pip

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

Since the day I started building my website, I installed many packages sometimes to test bunch of codes, sometimes for the project itself (Later I figured out it's not the package needed). But now, when I run `pip freeze` I have a list of packages, It becomes hard to me to uninstall packages that aren't used. I am about to deploy my website.

I'm using the latest version of `pip`, and running a Django Project
I have virtual environment with `virtualenv` **python 3.5**

OS: Linux (Ubuntu)

Many thanks you awesome people!

Comment: `pip uninstall` or create new virtualenv and run project inside it adding package one by one.

Comment: That's an idea, but there's no quick one? @BearBrown

Comment: sorry, but i don't know.

Comment: Anyway I really love your idea @BearBrown, I will go with it

Comment: Determining all used packages is tricky: first you have to check all the imports in your code and then there are `INSTALLED_APPS` - there are lots of Django apps whose code you never import in the projects. This is one of the use cases where having a good test suite with a 100% code coverage comes handy.

Comment: You can take a look at `pipdeptree` which can build a dependency tree from your installed packages. With it, you can list packages that were installed explicitly and are not just a dependency of some other package: `pipdeptree | grep -v '^ '`, this way you will have a lot less packages to test. Uninstall one package (use `pip-autoremove` to uninstall a package with all its dependencies), run the test suite, install back on failure, proceed to the next package on success.

Comment: I appreciate your answer @hoefling , I ended up uninstalling them, then I installed one by one those used in my project

Answer (score 0):

you can uninstall using a requirements package

simply create / take your requriements list like so:

```
django
flask
other_packages
```

put that in a text file called requirements.txt

then do

```
pip uninstall -r requirements.txt
```

or in your case

```
pip3 uninstall -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what if I don't know yet all the packages that aren't used, is there a way to achieve that

Comment: "pip3 list" will list all the packages installed

Comment: That's not what I was looking for, but you answer has driven me in the right direction.

Comment: oh packages that aren't used, you'll just have to cross reference with your imports and determine the ones that you don't need, Or uninstall everything and then reinstall everything as it is needed.

Comment: "pip uninstall -y -r <(pip freeze)" will uninstall all packages

Comment: I got it, but what I was looking is **a way to uninstall packages that aren't used in my project** because I installed lots of, so now it becomes hard to know which package is useless

Comment: ya so in that case it might be easier to uninstall everything and then reinstall what is needed.